# how many overlaps if we choose items randomly

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that I have $n$ items $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$. I am going to choose $p$ items randomly from them. Alice also chooses $p$ items out of the $n$ items.

What is the probability of having $k$ overlaps between my choice and Alice's choice?

---

my trial: The probability of each being chosen is $p/n$. So the prob of each being chosen twice is $(p/n)^2$. So this is a binomial process $B(n, (p/n)^2)$.

Therefore the probability of having $k$ overlaps is $\binom{n}{k} (p/n)^{2k} (1-(p/n)^2)^{n-k}$.

---

Is this correct? The point that I am confusing is that if we think each item will be chosen wp $p/n$, then it may violate our construction "choosing $p$ items in total". Because nothing will be chosen wp $(1-p/n)^n$?

Answer (score 4):

You can assume, without loss of generality, that one of the people specifically chooses items $\{X_1, \cdots, X_p\}.$

This is because the number of matches between the two people is unaffected by (i.e. independent of) which items the first person selected.

Therefore, the probability of having exactly $k$ matches can be expressed as

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$

where $~\displaystyle D = \binom{n}{p}.$

The number of ways that the second person can select $k$ items from the first $p$ items and $(p-k)$ items from the last $(n-p)$ items is

$$N = \binom{p}{k} \times \binom{n-p}{p-k}.$$

Putting this all together, I get

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{\binom{p}{k} \times \binom{n-p}{p-k}}{\binom{n}{p}}$$

$$=~ \frac{p!}{k! \times (p-k)!} \times \frac{(n-p)!}{(p-k)! \times  (n+k-2p)!} \times \frac{p! \times (n-p)!}{n!}$$

$$=~ \frac{(p!)^2 \times [(n-p)!]^2}{[(p-k)!]^2 \times (k!) \times [(n+k-2p)!] \times n!} \tag1 .$$

---

**However:**

The above analysis begs the question:

Does the OP's (i.e. original poster's) computation agree with mine?

If not, what mistake did the OP make?

---

> my trial: The probability of each being chosen is $p/n$. So the prob of each being chosen twice is $(p/n)^2$. So this is a binomial process $B(n, (p/n)^2)$.

> Therefore the probability of having $k$ overlaps is $\binom{n}{k} (p/n)^{2k} (1-(p/n)^2)^{n-k}$.

Basically, the OP's computation is wrong for only one reason: the individual events are not independent events.

For example, suppose that you have $n$ independent Bernoulli trials, each with a probability of success of $p$, where $q = (1-p)$.

Then, the probability of having exactly $k$ successes is in fact 
$~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} \times p^k \times q^{n-k}.$

However, suppose (for example) that item $X_1$ is selected twice.  This implies that the probability of item $X_2$ being selected twice is slightly smaller than normal.  So, if the OP's method is to be used, you have to deal with the complications of dependent events.  I strongly suspect that this makes the algebra a mess.

---

Finally, there is a separate issue:

Either the analysis at the start of my answer is valid, or it isn't.  If it is valid, then any alternative method of attack, that is also valid, must result in the same computation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your reason seems correct to me, it is exactly what I was thinking weird.
However, why do you think your analysis at the start might be invalid?
===> Ah I see, you are asking whether my answer == your answer. hm..

Comment: @Jayboy I don't think that my analysis is invalid.  I was simply playing Devil's Advocate as a way of emphasizing that it is insufficient to provide the accurate analysis.  If you are given any other analysis that results in a different computation, then you must also diagnose the flaw in the alternative analysis.  So, if anyone (for example) wanted to dispute my analysis with their own analysis, which leads to a different computation, then they would have the added burden of finding a flaw in my analysis.

Comment: @Jayboy This explains why, in my answer, it would have been insufficient to stop, at the point were the expression (1) was given.  I also had the burden of diagnosing the OP's computation.

Comment: I tried some numerical evaluation. for n=10, p=5, k=1, my answer gives 0.1877, your answer gives 0.0992.
I think yours is right, but let me think it more.
Thanks!!!

Comment: @Jayboy If you haven't already done so, I strongly urge you to develop at least the minimal programming skill necessary to **sanity-check** the problem, via a computer simulation.  Any programming language, like C, Java, or Python, should work.  If you don't know any languages, then Python should probably the language that you cut your teeth on.  The nice thing about being able to program is that you don't have to take anyone's word for the valid analysis.  You can use a computer simulation to determine the right answer.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Jayboy The idea is that if you have made no programming mistake, and your **candidate analysis** results in a different computation, then there must be some hidden flaw in your candidate analysis.  Sanity-checking is an extremely handy tool for problems that involve Combinatorics or Probability theory.  The one drawback is that the typical PC will run into problems if it has to deal with more than $(10)^8$ individual *cases*.